# Valence enrollments in orgUnit excluding some roles

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Is there a way to get only Staff-type enrollments in orgUnit, eg **exclude** role "student"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; the [GET /d2l/api/lp/(version)/enrollments/orgUnits/(orgUnitId)/users/](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-enrollments-orgUnits-%28orgUnitId%29-users-) action lets you specify a *roleId* query parameter to filter the result set down to enrollments with only that role. However, please note that the enrollments routes are mostly intended for use by administrative calling user contexts; if your use cases involve typical end user personas, like students and instructors, then you should use the classlist family of calls instead to help users inspect membership of their enrolled-in org units.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, but you answered a different question. I haven't asked about INCLUDING 1 role. My question is about EXCLUDING roles because I need to find all ACADEMICS enrolled in a Space (many possible roles), so I need to exclude Students.

Comment: If you make the call and specify `roleId=<AcademicsRoleId>` (whatever that might be), the call will send back only results that have that enrolled role, and not students. The call with no `roleId` query parameter fetches all enrolled users: specifying the query parameter fetches only the enrollments for that role. Accordingly, you will need to make the call in succession for each different role you want to retrieve: there isn't a way to batch a list of roles, or exclude one or more roles (except by specifying one).

Comment: OK. So, you confirmed that if I need enrollments in 4 different roles (Instructor, Tutor, Reviewer, Convenor) I need to execute 4 calls and there is no better way.